# ActiveReports 7 TextBox/List Page Break

Tags: activereports

I'm new to ActiveReports 7, I have a rdlx Report using a stored procedure to populate multiple lists with TextBoxes. The data is appearing correctly, however I am unable to get the TextBoxes to break when their contained data exceeds the length of the page. Instead, the TextBox remains unbroken and starts on the next page leaving a large empty gap. I have the containing Lists' 'KeepTogether' property set to 'False' and it doesn't help. How can I make these Lists and/or TextBoxes break at the end of the page and resume on the next?

Answer (score 0):

Check the type of report you have. There are the "ActiveReports 7 Page Report", aka FPL (Fixed Page Layout) report and the "CPL Report" (Continuous Page Layout).

Fixed Page Layout is for creating a new page for each record. Suitable for invoices and similar reports. You need a "CPL report" so that it only adds pageas as needed for the content.

To get a CPL Report take the following steps from inside the designer in Visual Studio:

1. Project > Add New Item
2. Choose the "ActiveReports 7 Page Report" item here.
3. Choose Report > Convert to CPL Report.

Those steps should effectively have the effect of changing "Page" to "Body".

Below are the steps I used to create a CPL report that has a list with a textbox containing very long text (longer than a page) and it renders across pages okay:

1. Add a list
2. Add a textbox to the list. The default properties should work fine, but the relevant properties on my textbox are:

   - TextBox.CanGrow=True
   - TextBox.WrapMode=WordWrap
   - List.KeepTogether=False: *Although technically this should be fine either way if the textbox/list are larger than a page. KeepTogether=False will just prevent it from moving to a new page if it is starting half way down the page.*

Let me know if you still don't crack it and I'll upload my test report here somewhere for you.

Comment: Thanks Scott. I am using the CPL-type report and have all parameters set as you describe. Unfortunately, I don't have it working yet. Your test report would be most welcomed and helpful.

Comment: @Jeff I put a zip at https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B07Bn13JpUvoMXhET0tXd2hvTWs/edit?usp=sharing See MyCplReport.rdlx